# Is right using preg_match to search word that contain specific letters?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a group of letters, for example :

```
$word='estroaroint';
```

that can be arranged to be words like :

```
- store
- train
- restoration
- ...etc
```

They can be found in my file list 'dictionary.txt'.

A letter only can only be used once.

How to write a php script able to perform that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to manage it with this function: `strpbrk()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpbrk.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But would you give me example in my case?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really possible to do that in one step with a regex. However, it is possible to do it in two steps:

- the first step find all the words in the dictionary that only contains the letters.
- the second step filter words where letters are repeated.

Example (only for ascii range):

```
$pattern = '~\b[' . $word . ']{1,' . strlen($word) . '}+\b~';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $dictionary, $m)) {
    $chars = count_chars ($word, 1);
    $result = array_filter($m[0], function ($i) use ($chars) {
        foreach (count_chars($i, 1) as $k=>$v) {
            if ($v > $chars[$k]) return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

    print_r($result);
}
```

PHP links: [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - [`count_chars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php)

Note: to extend this script to multibyte characters, you need to write your own function `mb_count_chars` (since this function doesn't exist) that splits a multibyte string (you can use for example `mb_substr`, `mb_strlen` and a loop, or `preg_split` with `~(?=.)~u` and the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` option). You need to add the `u` modifier to the regex pattern too and to change `strlen` to its multybyte equivalent.